# iPad 3G, is it only 3G

Tags: ipad

Can the iPad 3G only use 3G and Wifi, or can it use Edge or 2G (the little blue dot on iphone)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"**3G + WiFi**" is just a commercial tag line.

the 3G part stands for internet access throughout a mobile connection, usually using a SIM Card.

The **full range of connections** on a "3G" model **can be found in the [Technical Specifications](http://www.apple.com/ipad/specs/)** of the product, in this case:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The iPad uses the same mobile chip set as the iPhone and cam (depending on your data provider) use Edge (denoted by an E) or GPRS (seen as a circle).

O2 in the UK definitely does.

Comment: I can vouch that it works over EDGE.  My in-laws live in the Texas Panhandle and I only get EDGE reception there.